# file get content failed to process sometimes

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, session-variables, captcha

we are trying to create a captcha over files
but we face wired issue , sometimes file is process even though that it is existing

issue is appearing for first post request , and only sometimes not always
when repost it works fine

first we define path to file
`$this->filename = ASSETS_DIR . "login/" . session_id();`

create file if not post

```
if(count($_POST) <= 0){
            $imageText = rand(1000,9999);
            $myImage = createCapImg($imageText,'',session_id());
            file_put_contents($this->filename,$imageText);
        }
```

check file on post

`$capNum = file_get_contents($this->filename);`

issue :

`file_get_contents(assets/login/b10f9eb03d7c29a7dab4bb5970b6e827): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in`

Comment: Have you verified that the session ID actually stayed the same between those two requests, when the error occurs?

Comment: try to find  the size of the file using filesize  function  before calling file_get_contents. This will help to make sure file exists before it is read.      

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Comment: the first session id is already generted , the customer is able to see the captcha img ,but when he click send somehow the session either changes or deleted